# What is the reason for this error and how to fix it?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, data-binding, retrofit2

I am using `kotlin` for android with `databinding` with `MVVM` Pattern.
`Retrofit2` to send and get api calls.

When I am sending logIn call I always get crash and this is the message :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class java.lang.Object
```

I redesigned the response so many times and it actually matches the response from my api.
any Help if you please?

```
//my retrofit interface

interface RetrofitInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("userLogin")
    suspend fun userLogin(
        @Field("userName") userName: String,
        @Field("userPassword") userPassword: String
    ): Response<UserLoginResponse>



    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(
            networkConnectionInterceptor: NetworkConnectionInterceptor
        ): RetrofitInterface {
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(networkConnectionInterceptor)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl("http://muUrlIsCorrect/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(RetrofitInterface::class.java)

        }
    }

}

//My response class
data class UserLoginResponse(
    var error: Boolean?,
    var message: String?,
    var user: User?
)
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: What do you mean by full stacktrace ?

Comment: in LogCat, post the stacktrace error.

Comment: yeah, Just give me one minute please.

Comment: I can not post it all !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

I think you forgot to add `.addCallAdapterFactory` in your Retrofit.Builder()
Please add `.addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())` if you are using coroutines-kotlin otherwise you can add `.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())`

```
Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
           .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .build()
           .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
```

Try out this

Comment: CoroutineCallAdapterFactory  class belongs to this gradle  ->implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2' 

Just confirm that you have to add this gradle. if you already added this gradle then please describe your error?

Comment: Menas your first error is resolved right?
for Deffered you have to change Response<UserLoginResponse> to Deferred<Response<UserLoginResponse>>

For reference ->

@POST("userLogin")
    fun userLogin(@Query("userName") userName: String, @Query("userPassword") userPassword: String): Response<UserLoginResponse>

Comment: You need to give a full description of every error. without details of error can't help you.

Comment: How to get my user or even the message  from the response now?

Comment: You can use this way?  -->


GlobalScope.launch {
                try {
                    val response = service.userLogin("userName", "userPassword").await()
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        handleMovieResponse(response)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

Comment: still have the same error 
`
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class java.lang.Object 
`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes later for this issue.
It happens if your retrofit service methods are not suspended.
Make the methods suspended and this issue is resolved.

Comment: WAS SUSPENDED AND ALSO GAVE ME THE ERROR, TRY Akshay SOLUTION, IT IS WORK.

Answer (score 1):

addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())